# EJBQL Named Query - How to Sum BigDecimal

Tags: java, ejb, sum, bigdecimal, named-query

I have a BigDecimal representing money. I want to be able to select a sum of it in a NamedQuery but it won't sum BigDecimals.

```
@NamedQuery(name=Account.CALCULATE_TRANSACTIONS, query="SELECT SUM(a.credit) + SUM(a.debit) FROM Transaction a WHERE a.account.id = :accountId AND a.journalEntry.staged = false")
```

where credit and debit are BigDecimals. This doesn't work. What would be the best way to do this besides pulling them all out, iterating them and generating a total. I know I can do that but looking for a way to do it in one query if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try Criteria API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update/answer. From everything I have researched, this just isn't possible in EJBQL3. I had to do it outside the scope of the named queries.

Answer (score 0):

This post may be old but it may help someone else.

So I had the same problem reported here and I realize that you can only use `SUM` on numeric primitive types. eg `short`, `int`, `long`, `float` and `double`.

The `SUM` function cannot process a `null` value